# Pentoho How to check ,If at least one row is LDAP is 0 with same user mutiple times

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-design-studio

I have mutiple rows in Pentoho with Coulmn name LDAP flag

```
       Coulmn user id LDAP flag 
ROw 1          A         1
Row 2          B         1
Row 3          B         0
```

I need  row like below

```
    Coulmn user id LDAP flag 
ROw 1          A         1
Row 3          B         0
```

If atleast one row is 0 then I need to set  LDAP check is true

```
Coulmn User id LDAP flag
ROw 1     C      1
Row 2     C      1
Row 3     C      1

Coulmn User id LDAP flag
 Row 3     C      1
```

If all rows are  1 then  I need to set LDAP check is false

It is not working

I need  row like below

```
    Coulmn user id LDAP flag 
ROw 1          A         1
Row 3          B         0
```

If atleast one row is 0 then I need to set  LDAP check is true

```
Coulmn User id LDAP flag
ROw 1     C      1
Row 2     C      1
Row 3     C      1

Coulmn User id LDAP flag
 Row 3     C      1
```

If all rows are  1 then  I need to set LDAP check is false

It is not working